# Error: "free(): double free detected in tcache 2" - CS50 PSET 4: Recover

Tags: c, cs50

So this program attempts to recover the file data of some deleted JPEG images using fread() and fwrite(). Going through my code, I can't seem to find an error, but when I run the program with the raw data file, I get the error " free(): double free detected in tcache 2       Aborted (core dumped)"

Looking online this seems the be a memory allocation / freeing issue where some piece of memory is being freed multiple times, but I can't see how that's being done.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // ensure proper usage of program
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover img\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // rename and open the memory card
    char* inputf = argv[1];
    FILE *file = fopen(inputf, "r");

    // check that the memory card file is valid
    if(file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to Read Memory Card\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // set up buffer array
    BYTE buffer[512];

    // initialize jpegcounter
    int jpeg = 0;

    // allocate memory for filename
    char filename[9];

    // initialize a file for the bytes to be read into when needed
    FILE *JPEGPTR = NULL;

    while (fread(buffer, 512, 1, file) == 1)
    {
        if(buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {

            if (jpeg != 0)
            {
                fclose(JPEGPTR);
            }

            else
            {
                sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpeg", jpeg);
                JPEGPTR = fopen(filename, "w");
                if (JPEGPTR == NULL)
                {
                    printf("Could not create image. \n");
                    fclose(file);
                    return 1;
                }

                jpeg++;
                if (jpeg != 0)
                {
                    fwrite(buffer, 512, 1, JPEGPTR);
                }
            }
        }

    }
    fclose(JPEGPTR);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My guess is that the `filename` array is too small, Try with `char filename[30];` or so.

Comment: Likely because you're closing the `JPEGPTR` file twice in some specific flow, once inside the inner `if` within the `while` loop and another one after the `while` loop. Or because you're trying to close it while it's still `NULL`.

Comment: I don't see a direct call to `free()`, but it does look like it would be possible for the program to attempt to `fclose(JPEGPTR)` when `JPEGPTR` does not point to an open `FILE`.

Comment: @WilkMaia Wouldn't the first fclose(JPEGPTR) only trigger when a new file has been open in a subsequent loop, and the second one trigger at the end of the program? How would both trigger in a single flow?

Comment: @JohnBollinger would it fclose(JPEGPTR) while NULL if the file entered in the command line has no JPEG header BYTE signatures? Should I add an if statement to check that JPEGPTR != NULL before I fclose()?

Comment: At the end of the program you close `JPEGPTR` even if you never found a jpeg image in the raw file.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you for pointing that else statement out, I removed it and reformatted my code. 

I'm not sure why it would be bad practice to make the name array the exact size needed, if the name format is fixed at 8 characters, plus a nul. Wouldn't it be a waste of memory to include more than needed? (not that it's a real draw on the RAM or anything to include a few more BYTE's)

Comment: It is bad practice because it makes people ask if it is big enough, and if there should be more than 999 files it will overflow too. Just make it big enough to handle anything, say `char filename[32]`. Memory is cheap: a few bytes isn't much of a 'waste' when you have megabytes available.

Comment: @WeatherVane Good point, I'll correct that now. 

I went back through my loop logic for the fwrite as well, the program works as intended now. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `else` should not be there.

This code block will only execute once, and the third and subsequent loops will attempt to close a file that was not open.

It's worth noting too that `fwrite` will be called only when the header was detected.

So re-examine the loop logic. Proper formatting helps with understanding the flow of control.